# Parse - Users trying to login with FB after creating account manual - iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, parsing

I am giving to my users the options to sign up manually or using Facebook(I am using Parse). The problem now is that if a user has signup manually and then try to login with Facebook is creating a second account and leaves the email valun to null(becuase already exists). So what is the solution for this one? Is there any official solution? I tried a workaround:

```
FBRequest *requestEmail = [FBRequest requestForMe];

 [requestEmail startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

NSLog(@"Error %@",error);

NSDictionary *userData2 = (NSDictionary *)result;

NSString *email2=userData2[@"email"];

PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
[query whereKey:@"email" equalTo:email2];
[query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {


    NSString *emailQue =[object objectForKey:@"email"];

    if(error || (emailQue==NULL) || (emailQue==nil)){

        NSLog(@"User facebook account does not exist");
    }
    else{

        NSLog(@"User facebook email exist");
        NSLog(@"email %@",emailQue);
    }


}];
}];
```

which is failing (No active token available) and I believe this is not the correct way. Even if this work then I cant stop the loginWithPermission to create the new user once canceled.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If you know that this user is an existing PFUser you can instead link their Facebook account with their existing account. This is a supported Parse feature.

```
if (![PFFacebookUtils isLinkedWithUser:user]) {
    [PFFacebookUtils linkUser:user permissions:nil block:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
        if (succeeded) {
            NSLog(@"Woohoo, user logged in with Facebook!");
        }
    }];
}
```

You can get the current user with

```
PFUser *currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];
```

Or you could even convert an Anonymous user to a Facebook user.

https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#fbusers-link/iOS

Comment: Hi and thanks for your answer. My problem is when the user is not logged in. i know i can linked them but only once the user has logged in

Comment: I see, you could do what you're suggesting and retrieve email from facebook and check to see if it exists, if so link the account, if not a new account is created for them. Or maybe a better experience would be to inform them they have already signed up with that email address would they like to link this facebook account?

Comment: The problem is that the login method is creating automatically a new user if does not exist on it's database. It would be nice to inform them that they already have account BUT you cant avoid the creaetion of the user. also the next time that the user will hit the login with facebook its going to logged him in with with the useless account that created before

Comment: You could try and use the FacebookSDK component of the ParseSDK to just authenticate a user (as per FB docs not Parse) and then perform the requestForMe to get their email. Once you know whether that is an existing user or not then you use the Parse methods for linking or creating. More complicated I know, but I'm surprised Parse doesn't handle this scenario.